# Javascript select switch select on change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have 2 selects, one switch the other while changing

```
<select class="select-global-132" name="tipo" id="tipo" onchange="tipo_cambio()">
        <option value="Digital" selected>Seleccionar</option>

          <option value="Boleta">Boleta</option>
          <option value="Factura">Factura</option>
          <option value="Traslado">Guia de Despacho</option>
          </select>
```

and number two

```
<select style="display:none;" name="iva" id="iva" >
            <option value="0" selected>No</option>
            <option value="19">Aplicar 19%</option>


            </select>
```

The javascript that does the trick set TAXES while option 2 or 3 in first select but I just added a new option and it must NOT add taxes but it does anyway

A way to try to fix it is the follow

```
function tipo_cambio () {
var tipo = document.getElementsByName('tipo')[0];
if ( tipo.value == "Digital")
if ( tipo.value == "Traslado")
     taxes.selectedIndex = 0;

else taxes.selectedIndex = 1;
```

but it is not really working it add taxes anyway. I need it to NOT set taxes 19% when set to first or last option but apply the taxes (switch the other select) with options 2 and 3 only

The problem is here but I am not good with javascript

```
if ( tipo.value == "Digital")
if ( tipo.value == "Traslado")
```

any idea?

Here the entire javascript code

```
var taxes    = document.getElementsByName('iva')[0];
var discount = document.getElementsByName('descuento')[0];
var cost     = document.getElementsByName('neto')[0];
var price    = document.getElementsByName('preciodesc')[0];
var tneto   = document.getElementsByName('totalneto')[0];
var ttaxes   = document.getElementsByName('ivaunitario')[0];
var ivatot   = document.getElementsByName('ivatotal')[0];
var total    = document.getElementsByName('subtotal')[0];
var quantity = document.getElementsByName('cantidad')[0];
var ttp      = document.getElementsByName('total')[0];
var micosto      = document.getElementsByName('costo')[0];
var costotot      = document.getElementsByName('costototal')[0];
var migan      = document.getElementsByName('ganancia')[0];
var gantot      = document.getElementsByName('gananciatotal')[0];

function updateInput() {
  price.value = cost.value - (cost.value * (discount.value / 100));
  ttaxes.value = (price.value * (taxes.value / 100));
  ivatot.value = parseFloat(ttaxes.value) * parseFloat(quantity.value);

  costotot.value = parseFloat(micosto.value) * parseFloat(quantity.value);
  migan.value = parseFloat(price.value) - parseFloat(micosto.value);
  gantot.value = parseFloat(migan.value) * parseFloat(quantity.value);


  tneto.value = parseFloat(price.value) * parseFloat(quantity.value);
  var sum = parseFloat(price.value) + parseFloat(ttaxes.value);
  total.value = sum.toFixed(0);
  ttp.value = sum.toFixed(0) * quantity.value;
}

taxes.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
discount.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
cost.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
cost.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
quantity.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);

function tipo_cambio () {
var tipo = document.getElementsByName('tipo')[0];
if ( tipo.value == "Digital")
if ( tipo.value == "Traslado")
     taxes.selectedIndex = 0;

else taxes.selectedIndex = 1;
updateInput();
}
```

Comment: [how to use if statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) you'll want to do `if (tipo.value === "Digital" || tipo.value === "Traslado") taxes.selectedIndex = 0` The way you have the if statement right now is not doing what you want

Comment: You are correct it worked. Thanks a lot, Could you please answer to choose your answer as correct for future users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. maybe this can help you.. you can use jquery for now

```
function tipo_cambio () {
var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
if ( $('#tipo').val() == "Digital"){

}else if ( $('#tipo').val() == "Traslado"){
    $('#iva').show();
    $('#iva').val(19);    
}else {
    $('#iva').val(0);    
    updateInput();
}
```

}

Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w9s6s5np/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the error was with the if statement not performing as intended by the developer. The solution: use an or operator

```
 if (tipo.value === "Digital" || tipo.value === "Traslado")
```